# Insert hyperlinks to a XWPFParagraph to another Paragraph in a XWPFDocument

Tags: java, hyperlink, xwpf

I want to make the text inside an `XWPFParagraph` (start) a hyperlink to another concrete `XWPFParagraph` (end) in the doc. I found a code to make hyperlinks inside an `XWPFCell`, but it's not working (start links to start):

```
    private static void createHyperlink(XWPFParagraph start, XWPFParagraph end, String endText, String startText) {

    CTHyperlink cLink = end.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
    cLink.setAnchor(startText);

    CTText ctText = CTText.Factory.newInstance();
    ctText.setStringValue(endText);
    CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.newInstance();
    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[] { ctText });


    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[] { ctr });
    start.getCTP().setHyperlinkArray(new CTHyperlink[] { cLink });
    end.getCTP().removeHyperlink(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it. The original idea was to create an hyperlink from a XWPFParagraph to another XWPFParagraph, but as I will always link to a paragraph with an unique text in the doc, I found it out this way:

```
    private static void createHyperLink(XWPFParagraph start, String startTxt, String endTxt) {

        // Creating the hyperlink in the start paragraph
        CTHyperlink cLink = start.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();

        // Link to the end text in the doc
        cLink.setAnchor(endTxt);

        // Creating the String that will have the hyperlink
        CTText ctText = CTText.Factory.newInstance();
        ctText.setStringValue(startTxt);
        CTR ctr=CTR.Factory.newInstance();
        ctr.setTArray(new CTText[]{ctText});

        // Inserting the String in the doc
        cLink.setRArray(new CTR[]{ctr});            
    }
```